# Из многоуровнего json вывести все ключи

Tags: json, bash

Есть например json:

```
{ 
    "SALUTATION": 
        { 
            "Hellow":"world"
        }, 
    "SOMETHING": "bla bla bla Mr. Freeman" 
}
```

Из него нужно вывести все ключи: `SALUTATION`, `Hellow`, `SOMETHING` средствами bash.

Если использовать jq 'keys':

```
JSON='{ "SALUTATION": { "Hellow": "world" }, "SOMETHING": "bla bla bla Mr. Freeman" }'
echo $JSON | jq 'keys'
```

На выходе получаю `["SALUTATION", "SOMETHING"]`, т.е. только ключи первого уровня. Хочу понять, как выводить все ключи, вне зависмости от того, на каком они уровне.

Comment: У вас тег `bash`, вам надо с помощью консольных утилит решить вопрос? Напишите, что и как пытались сделать и пр., на SO не решают чужие задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если отбросить возможное повторения ключей в json, то как-то так:

```
$ JSON='{ "SALUTATION": { "Hellow": "world" }, "SOMETHING": "bla bla bla Mr. Freeman" }'
$ echo $JSON | jq -r '. | paths[]'| sort -u
Hellow
SALUTATION
SOMETHING
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

недавно опубликованная мной shell утилитка *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* позволяет обойти все/любые JSON элементы (включая ключи). Полученный результат уже можно обработать с помощью стандартных shell комманд - отбросить значения и отсортировать уникальные элементы:

```
bash $ JSON='{ "SALUTATION": { "Hellow": "world" }, "SOMETHING": "bla bla bla Mr. Freeman" }'
bash $ echo $JSON | jtc -w'<.*>L:' -lr | sed 's/":.*/"/' | sort -u
"Hellow"
"SALUTATION"
"SOMETHING"
bash $
```

**UPDATE**:
за прошлый год, я довел программу до завершения - она покрывает практически все сценарии работы с JSON. теперь этаже задачка решается так:

```
bash $ <<<$JSON jtc -w'<.*>L:<>k' 
"SALUTATION"
"Hellow"
"SOMETHING"
bash $
```

Если нужно, например, вывести все ключи отсортированными:

```
bash $ <<<$JSON jtc -jw'<.*>L:<>k' / -w'><g:'
"Hellow"
"SALUTATION"
"SOMETHING"
bash $
```